# Audio dials 'onclick' not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, onclick

I've created some custom audio dials for my website that start playing (at zero volume) when the user engages (onclick) with the audio dial and then allow the user to increase the volume using the dial if they wish. This works fine in desktop but doesn't work at all on mobile.

My thinking that it is something to do with my call to function `play()` not working because mobiles don't support `onclick`?

Any help would be much appreciated

HTML

```
<img src="images/fire.png" class="audio-icons " id="fire-icon">
<input type="range" oninput="setVolume(this)" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
<audio loop id="cs_audio" controls style="display:none">
  <source src="audio/fire_loop.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

JS

```
var audio_file_1;
var volume1;

function init() {
  audio_file_1 = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
  volume1 = document.getElementById("volume1");
  audio_file_1.play();
}

function setVolume() {
  var audio_file_1 = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
  audio_file_1.volume = document.getElementById("volume1").value;

}

function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
  audio.play();
}
```